# Build a list of lists using a loop in Python

Tags: python, list, loops

I am trying to build long lists of boolean elements to be associated to trace visibility in `plotly` using the `python` api.

My input is:

```
list_true = list( np.ones(3, dtype=bool) )
list_false = list( np.zeros(3, dtype=bool) )
blocks = [1,2,3]
```

How should I define a loop that builds a list of lists so that the position of `list_true` blocks varies depending on the value of the index `blocks[i]`?. The ouput should be:

```
combination1 = list_true + list_false + list_false
combination2 = list_false + list_true + list_false
combination3 = list_false + list_false + list_true
```

that is:

```
combination1 = [
True, True, True,
False, False, False,
False, False, False,
]
combination2 = [
False, False, False,
True, True, True,
False, False, False,
]
combination3 = [
False, False, False,
False, False, False,
True, True, True,
]
```

Comment: Can you explain further, because none of *combination_1* or *combination_2* or *combination_3* is a list of lists. They are rather list of boolean.

Comment: @OdamePrince you are right, my mistake. I am not seeking to create a list of lists, but rather longer lists that are made of combination of `list_true` and `list_false` sublists

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

list_true = list(np.ones(3, dtype=bool))
list_false = list(np.zeros(3, dtype=bool))
blocks = [1,2,3]

combination = []
for i in blocks:
    sub_combination = [list_false for k in range(3)]
    sub_combination[i-1] = list_true
    combination.append(sub_combination [0] + sub_combination [1] + sub_combination [2])

print('combination1')
print(combination[0])

print('combination2')
print(combination[1])

print('combination3')
print(combination[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly and combination should be a list of lists (matrix basicly) you can do it like this (to solve it more elegantly I have not seperated the combination variables but made a list of combinations):

```
import numpy as np

list_true = list(np.ones(3, dtype=bool))
list_false = list(np.zeros(3, dtype=bool))
blocks = [1,2,3]

combination = []
for i in range(len(blocks)):
    combination.append([list_true, list_true, list_true])
    combination[i][i] = list_false

print(combination)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a generic function to insert a list at position of N and apply it to your true and false lists. The good thing is that you are not restricted to totally 3 lists as in your example. You can have as many lists as you wish (change user defined total n and use it as an argument of function put_true).

You can also give any list you want to the function. You can decide which one you are interested in (chose L_insert, the true list in your example) and which are those you will just use to fill the blanks (chose L2, the false list in your example).

```
import numpy as np
list_true = list(np.ones(3, dtype=bool) )
list_false = list(np.zeros(3, dtype=bool) )
blocks = [1,2,3]

# generic function to insert list L_insert among L2s
# which list to be inserted, to which position within how many lists
# can all be defined by user
def insert_list(L_insert, L2):
    def insert_at_n(n_insert, n_total):
        if n_total == 0:
            return []
        elif n_insert == 1:
            return L_insert + insert_at_n(n_insert-1, n_total-1) 
        else:
            return L2 + insert_at_n(n_insert-1, n_total-1)
    return insert_at_n

put_true=insert_list(list_true, list_false)
total = 3 # if you want more false list to be appended, simply change this number
put_true_at_n = lambda n: put_true(n, total)

combination1 = put_true_at_n(1)
combination2 = put_true_at_n(2)
combination3 = put_true_at_n(3)
...
combinationn = put_true_at_n(n)

# an additional benefit is that you can simply apply it to a list of integers
# in order to automatize your work    
print([put_true_at_n(n) for n in blocks])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my issue, which changes with the length of the `blocks` list (as intended) and flattens the combined (nested) list into the desired result. Thanks to @Odame Prince for the tip.

```
import numpy as np

list_true = list(np.ones(3, dtype=bool))
list_false = list(np.zeros(3, dtype=bool))
blocks = ['A','B','C','D']

for i in range(len(blocks)):
    combo_list = [list_false for k in range(len(blocks))]
    combo_list[i] = list_true    
    flat_list = [item for sublist in combo_list for item in sublist]
    print('\nCombination{}:  {}'.format(i, flat_list) )
```

Returns:

```
Combination0:  [True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]

Combination1:  [False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False]

Combination2:  [False, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False, False]

Combination3:  [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, True]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this shorter version with [insert](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html):

```
list_true = np.ones(3, dtype=bool)
list_false = np.zeros(3, dtype=bool)

blocks = [1, 2, 3]

initial = [np.repeat(list_false, 2) for i in range(3)]
final = [np.insert(initial[b-1], (b-1)*3, list_true) for b in blocks]
```